# Going out by adding a tile and a joker to a run in Rummikub

Tags: rummikub, joker

I have seen many posts about using a joker from a player's rack or replacing a joker on the table. My question relates to using a joker at the end of a game to declare Rummikub.

Here's the scenario:

- I have one tile, a `Red 5`, in my rack.
- Since I cannot go out, I draw from the bag and get a `Joker`.
- Next time it is my turn, there is a run of `Red 1,2,3` on the table.

Can I use my `Joker` (as a `Red 4`) and my `Red 5` to add to the run on the table and declare Rummikub?

The rules seem to imply:

- That you can only use a joker from your rack with two other tiles, and
- That you also have to make a new set.

But at the end of game you do not have sufficient tiles to do this.